# WordPress - Visual Composer won't edit a page via page builder

Tags: wordpress

I installed WP bakery and hoping that a theme that was made using Visual Composer will able me to edit the page.

[image]

[image]

However upon installing the plugin its still doesn't convert the codes to Visual Composer page builder and there is no link to edit pages via visual composer:

[image]

Any idea what's up with this?

Comment: This is the Gutenberg editor - switch to the classic one for VC to work properly

Comment: Where can I find that?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/

Comment: or https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/

Comment: So installing these two plugins will solve the problem?

Comment: You don't need both - they are just two alternatives

Comment: pick your favourite

Comment: If you are using the gutenberg editor, somewhere else on your site, and want to keep it - then I would suggest using the `disable gutenberg` one, since you can choose where to disable it

Comment: Gutenberg should be an option, and not forced upon us. glad to help

Comment: I agree. It was my first having such issue.